# How to store multi select values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, formbuilder

I have many to many relationship between categories and movies. When I check multiple values for categories and insert movie the result on home page selects only one category not all. I tried many things but I wasn't able to resolve this. Here is my code.

upload.blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::pluck('category_name', 'id')->all();
    return view('movies.upload', compact('categories'));
}

public function upload(MovieUploadRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $movie = Movie::create($request->all());
        $movie->categories()->attach($request->get('category_id'));
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
    }

    return redirect('home');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable multiple selects, you first of need to change the name of the select input from `category_id` to `category_id[]`. This enables posting of multiple variables as an array.

The code should then look like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id[]', $categories, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
</div>
```

In your controller, you will then need to loop through the posted id's:

```
public function upload(...){
    foreach( $request->input('category_id') AS $category_id ){
        $movie = Movie::create($request->all());
        $movie->categories()->attach($category_id);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The method attach() also accepts an array of ids as an argument. Thereby, you don't need to loop through the input as above, but can simply use:

```
public function upload(...){
    $movie = Movie::create($request->all());
    $movie->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! But now I have a small problem on home page. When I insert movie with eg. two categories then second category moves to the right and enters where it should be some other <td>, it doesn't print two categories next to each other, if you know what i mean. How to solve that?

Comment: @Gacho to answer that I would need to see the markup for it. However if it works, you should accept the answer, and create a new one for your "styling issue"

Comment: @foreach($movies as $movie)
<tr>
<td><a href="{{ route('mov.edit', $movie->id) }}">{{$movie->name}}</a></td>
@foreach($movie->categories as $category)
<td><a href="{{ route('cat.edit', $category->id) }}">{{$category>category_name}}</a></td>
@endforeach

Comment: Like I said. You should post this as its own question, since it has nothing to do with your original one. Comment fields are not ment to start new question threads. And ofcourse each category becomes a td, since you have <td></td> inside the foreach loop. <td>Name of movie</td><td>@foreach($category AS $cat) {{ $cat->name }} @endforeach</td>...

Answer (score 2):

In your view, use a name like :

```
<select name="yourfiled[]"></select>.
```

In controller, to store it in database, just write

```
$movies->categories = json_encode(yourfield);
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this. hopefully this will solve your problem

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id[]', $categories, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
</div>
```